# Question about char pointers

Tags: c

I am confused with this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* ptr="MET ADSD";

    *ptr++;
    printf("%c\n", ptr);

    ptr++;
    printf("%c\n", ptr);
}
```

Here's the output.

> ET ADSD
>   T ADSD

My question is how does the pointer display the rest of the characters?

Comment: as comments have shown, it looks like this *isn't* the C code you actually ran, because you must have used `%s` not `%c`. Please be careful to ensure that the example you submit is exactly what you ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a wrong combination of parameters to `printf`: the `%c` format specification requires a `char` parameter, not a `char*`. So the result is undefined - in your case `printf` seems to print the whole char array, but this is just by pure chance. Use either

```
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

Comment: +1. And if you compile under strict settings, the compiler will warn you. For example, `gcc -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall <file.c> -o<file>`

Answer (score 4):

You are actually trying to print as a char `%c` a pointer value `char*`. This is false. But then, I really don't understand why it prints all the chars. Are you sure you didn't use `%s` instead of `%c`?

Answer (score 3):

The * operator as lower precedence over the ++ operator. Thus in your example the both lines

```
*ptr++;
ptr++;
```

have the same effect.

And you are using the wrong types in your printf statement.

Change

```
printf("%c\n", ptr);
```

to

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

or

```
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
```

depending on what you want to output.

Btw, turning on compiler warnings helps in that case. E.g. the GCC prints:

```
d.c: In function ‘main’:
d.c:7: warning: value computed is not used
d.c:8: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
d.c:11: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’
d.c:12: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Answer (score 2):

In C a *string* is a *array of chars*, and an *array* is simply a pointer to the first location of memory of the array.
So defining

```
char* ptr="MET ADSD";
```

you are declaring and initializing an array of chars, a string, by using a pointer to char,

The *next trick* comes if you consider this two factors:

- **pointers arithmetic** in that using the operator `++` on a pointer increments its value, the memory address it is pointing to
- **char size** which is almost everywhere 1 byte

So you are scaling the array along of two positions, and you print that by using `%s` and passing the pointer to it

**EDIT** I guess you put %c mistakenly in the example

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting 'E' as first and 'T' as second output.  Give it like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* ptr="MET ADSD";

    *ptr++;
    printf("%c\n", *ptr);

    ptr++;
    printf("%c\n", *ptr);
}
```

Comment: so do you mean to say that %s treats character array as a string?

Comment: @Searock: It does but the point being made was that you needed to dereference the pointer (`*ptr`) to get the character being pointed to.

Comment: @Searock Exactly, but even i don't understand why it prints whole string with %c, it should print the char. equivalent of the address i.e. something like if ptr=1057, then (char)1057

Answer (score 1):

printf( ..., ptr) is passing the pointer, not the char it points to.
The correct version of the program would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* ptr = "MET ADSD";
  ptr++;
  printf("%c\n", *ptr);
  ptr++;
  printf("%c\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

which will print

```
E
T
```

The output you are seeing makes no sense unless you are using %s. - %c is going to convert the value of ptr into an integer, truncate the int to 8bits (the width of a char), and print that character to the output. Not a string of characters.